# What would be the best table structure for variable amount of combination?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, atomic

I need some advice for the choice of my table structure.

I am working on a project where I need to save values that are a combination of a variable amount of other values.

For example:

```
A = b,c,d
B = z,r
```

I was thinking on saving the combinations in a json object inside a column but I am afraid it can be long for big requests and not easy for filtering.

There was also the solution of having a multiple amount of columns (containing null when not necessary), but this will not be a good representation of the data, also filtering will be hard.

Finally I thought the best would be many to many relations, but the joins might be too heavy, are they ?

Do you see any other alternative (besides switching to nosql) ?

Comment: go with a junction table approach. It will outperform anything you think you are helping the db engine by doing. And the storage of data won't be a facepalm moment when seen by peers

Comment: thank you for the advice I think I will go for it. How does mysql processes handles the joins when repeated ? I mean if my junction table contains foreign keys, will the joined data "retrieving process" be processed for every row with the same value ? or once it is retrieved for an FK value it is "cached" or saved for other rows with the same value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the use of Junction tables to avoid saving data in comma separated lists, json, or other mechanisms that would be problematic in at least these areas:

- Tables-scans (slowness, non-use of fast indexes)
- Maintenance of data
- Data integrity

### Schema

```
create table cat
(   -- categories
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    code varchar(20) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null
);

create table subcat
(   -- sub categories
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    code varchar(20) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null
);

create table csJunction
(   -- JUNCTION table for cat / sub categories
    -- Note: you could ditch the id below, and go with composite PK on (catId,subCatId)
    -- but this makes the PK (primary key) thinner when used elsewhere
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    catId int not null,
    subCatId int not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_csj_cat FOREIGN KEY (catId) REFERENCES cat(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_csj_subcat FOREIGN KEY (subCatId) REFERENCES subcat(id),
    unique key (catId,subCatId) -- prevents duplicates
);


insert cat(code,description) values('A','descr for A'),('B','descr for B'); -- id's 1,2 respectively

insert subcat(code,description) values('b','descr for b'),('c','descr for c'),('d','descr for d');  -- id's 1,2,3
insert subcat(code,description) values('r','descr for r'),('z','descr for z'); -- id's 4,5

-- Note that due to the thinness of PK's, chosen for performance, the below is by ID
insert csJunction(catId,subCatId) values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3); -- A gets a,b,c
insert csJunction(catId,subCatId) values(2,4),(2,5);    -- B gets r,z
```

### Good Errors

The following errors are good and expected, data is kept clean

```
insert csJunction(catId,subCatId) values(2,4); -- duplicates not allowed (Error: 1062)
insert csJunction(catId,subCatId) values(13,4); -- junk data violates FK constraint (Error: 1452)
```

### Other comments

In response to your comments, data is cached only in so far as mysql has a Most Recently Used (MRU) strategy, no more or less than any data cached in memory versus physical lookup.

The fact that `B` may contain not only `z,r` at the moment, but it *could* also contain `c` as does `A`, does not mean there is a repeat. And as seen in the schema, no parent can duplicate its containment (or repeat) of a child, which would be a data problem anyway.

Note that one could easily go the route of PK's in cat and subcat using the `code` column. That would unfortunately cause wide indexes, and even wider composite indexes for the junction table. That would slow operations down considerably. Though the data maintenance could be visually more appealing, I lean toward `performance` over `appearance` any day.

I will add to this Answer when time permits to show such things as "What categories contain a certain subcategory", deletes, etc.